# Trying to understand async and then

Tags: flutter, dart

I wrote this simple code:

```
import 'dart:io';

Future<int> f() async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
  return 7;
}

void main() {
  int a = 3;
  Future b = f();
  b.then( (value) {
    print("b value received: " + value.toString() );
    a = value;
  } );
  print(a);
  sleep(const Duration(seconds: 6));
  print(a);
  print("end");
}
```

Function f, in a secondary thread, will return a 7 after 3 seconds.

In the main function, I have a = 3.

Called function f, returning Future b.

When b receives its value, I would print "b value received", and assing b to a.

What I was expecting:

```
- print a -> 3
- after 3 seconds:
- b value received: 7
- after more 3 seconds:
- print a -> 7
- print end
```

What I have received:

```
- 3
- (after 6 seconds)
- 3
- end
- b value received: 7
```

What did I understand wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expectation of how `async` works is right.
The problem is not `async`, but the fact that you used `sleep` to test it.

`sleep` doesn't just force the function to pause. It makes the entire application pause, which includes the pending futures.

Instead, use `await Future.delayed`:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

Future<int> f() async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
  return 7;
}

void main() async {
  int a = 3;
  Future b = f();
  b.then((value) {
    print("b value received: " + value.toString());
    a = value;
  });
  print(a);
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 6));
  print(a);
  print("end");
}
```

which prints:

```
3
b value received: 7
7
end
```